# Strategy to terminate database job from a remote program utilizing cron

Tags: java, sql, oracle, cron, database-backups

**I have not yet coded a potential solution to this, so before anyone asks I have zero code to back this up as I am trying to get a firm grip on the processing behind what needs to happen.**

My problem is that I have an Oracle database that will be firing off jobs constantly (every 10 minutes or so) and I need a safe way (security wise and data integrity wise), to terminate these jobs and prevent them from executing while a nightly back up takes place.  For the sake of discussion this will be done via a cron job.  The way I think it should work is that the cron job will fire off at a time of 1 am (or some other low usage time, by low I mean < .001% of the user base will be interacting with the system).  The java process will need to execute some PL/SQL function on the database that does the following things:

```
1)  A force terminate on all running jobs  
2)  A snapshot of data that is to be written to an arbitrary directory  
3)  Restart all jobs  (mark them as enabled instead of disabled)
```

My question is this:

How can this be accomplished with the minimum amount of permissions and does this loose architecture facilitate the ability to prevent data corruption, assuming Oracle is correctly generating undo/redo logs?  IF this is an insecure/poor way of doing this, any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: i believe that if you do an (old style by now) EXP - then any running job will pick up where it left off on the corresponding IMP.  fwiw

Comment: @Randy Not sure I follow, could you elaborate?

Comment: in other words, you should be able to cron an EXP - without worrying about running jobs.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 10+ DBMS_Scheduler has a window definition that does exactly what you want. When the window ends, processing of running jobs can be terminated.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_sched.htm